# Regex for decimal in a Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a text box on a web page. I want it to only accept decimals with a max of 15 digits before the decimal and 4 after it. Such as `123456789012345.1234` but to also allow `.12` and `1` etc...

This is what I'm currently using to allow all the different variations of the decimal

> [+-]?\d+(.\d*)?|.\d+

To add the max no of digits allowed, I'm thinking something along the lines of this

> [+-]?\d{0,15}+(.\d{0,4})?|.\d{0,4}+

but I get the error `parsing "[+-]?\d{0,15}+(\.\d{0,4})?|\.\d{0,4}+" - Nested quantifier +.` when I try to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{n,m}` is a quantifier. As such, you shouldn't put another quantifier after it (`+`).

Try:

```
[+-]?\d{0,15}(\.\d{0,4})?|\.\d{0,4}
```

Your periods should be escaped.

---

Just as a side note, `{n,m}+` is a valid quantifier in certain regex engines, and it indicates a possessive behaviour.

Comment: So the {1,15} replaces the + after the \d ?

Comment: @Noelle The `{0,15}`, yes. If you want at least one digit, of course, you need to use `{1,15}`.